# if $f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ is an even function,show that $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \,dt$ is an odd function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

if $f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ is an even function, show that $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \,dt$ is an odd function

**My attempt:**

Given $f$ is even then $f(-x)=f(x)$

then $f(-x)=\int f(-x) dx=\int f(x) dx$ that is $f(x) =  \int f(x) dx$  is even but have to show this is odd function

Comment: Do a more careful substitution in $\int f(-x) dx$.

Comment: Hi, note that your question has been edited. Please check if this is still want you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is even, write $f(t) = f(-t)$:
\begin{align*}
F(-x) &= \int_0^{-x}f(t)\,dt = \int_0^{-x}f(-t)\,dt.
\end{align*}
Now set $u(t) = -t$, so that $u(0) = 0$, $u(-x) = x$, and $u'(t) = -1$.
By change of variable,
$$
\int_0^{-x}f(-t)\,dt = -\int_0^xf(u)\,du = -F(x),
$$
as desired.

Comment: @AOrtiz...when we substitute u=-t and d=-dt then total integral +

Comment: @suresh I updated my answer.

Comment: Very witty! I will have to add this to my repertoire of integral tricks…